# Duplicate of tree node

Tags: extjs4.1, treepanel

I've read a lot of complaints about the treepanel, now I'm having some trouble with it.

The first is that paging in the treegrid isn't working correctly. I found a solution in another post that doesn't work, so I'm trying to fix it for everybody.

The second is where I need help. The first time a parent node is expanded, it make a call to the server and displays the children correctly. When I collapse and then expand it again, however, it will paint the same child twice. The tree crashes, showing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'internalId' of undefined
```

After working on it, I discovered that the problem is not when it inserts it again, but in the `beforeitemexpand` function. It appends the same child  twice, causing the js and the `treestore` to contain 2 nodes with the same `internalId`, which in turn causes the crash.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The way tree store works is a bit complicated. I suspect the issues you are having are related to the idProperty of the **models** your tree store is storing.

I ran into these issues as well. I found out you can not have two records with the same identity in mutliple places in the tree. For example if your tree was representing a file system and you copied the same file into two directories. If your file had an idProperty (set to id by default) the store puts your file model into a hash keyed off the id, regardless of it's path in the tree.

The suggested solution was to either not have the id set at all (not a very good solution for an editable tree grid), or to set a compound key that takes into account the entire chain of nodes up to the root to grantee uniqueness in the tree.

Once you get passed these issues the tree works fairly well. Oh, and paging the tree ... don't think that will happen any time soon, already asked.

Comment: hey dbring, thanks for answering!, 
the problem i see is that it is calling twice to expand, maybe it have something to do with the id's, but i never configure the id of the nodes, and it still duplicate the same... I have work in this like 3 days and i cant solve this :(

Comment: You are going to have to post some code or better yet a jsfiddle that demonstrates your behavior